# Lumia 920 Screen does not respond with keys blink for few seconds

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, lock-screen, display, screen

I am having Nokia lumia 920. Sometimes my phone's screen does not work. I pressed the unlock key but it does not makes any difference. Keys blink for few seconds and goes off again. Then when i tried to call it from another cell it worked and display worked fine. It has happened two times in previous three days. It is worrying me please suggest me. I have Black software update in my phone but the problem is similar to this [Thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpupdate/amber-update-lock-screen-problem-lumia-820/3661649a-0209-476d-aaf8-56987e30b157?page=2). Also my phone's info is here in the image.!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the problem persists, then you really only have two options:

1. Reset the phone to the factory settings and hope that it helps
2. Get the phone replaced under warranty

In both cases you will lose all of your data, so make sure that you have a backup.